# JavaScript return false is not working

Tags: javascript

I'am trying to use google invisible reCAPTCHA with AJAX. But returne false is not working.

JS:

```
function onSubmit(token) {
        var siteurl= 'http://localhost/test/';
        document.getElementById("register").submit();
        var formdata = $('.register').serialize();
        $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: siteurl+"app/ajax/test.php",
                data: formdata
            })
            .done(function( msg ) {
                alert(msg);

            });
        return false
    }
```

HTML:

```
<form id="register" action="" method="post" class="register">
 <input class="for-1" type="text" name="field" >
 <input class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LfCqCAUAAAAAAjaAg5w_mHK" data-callback='onSubmit' type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

this codes working well but not returning false.
iam waiting help,
thanks.

Comment: `false` is going to be returned before your AJAX even finishes... Where are you expecting it to return to?

Comment: you must pass a callback if you want to use the result in your ajax

Comment: iam not  expecting any reload in this page. After all things done, it should be returne false.

Comment: @J.Titus—that's likely intended. I think the OP wants to stop the form submitting, but *return false* isn't doing the job.

Comment: Calling `document.getElementById("register").submit();` from within the submit? handler of the submit button of that form is **very** weird.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you wan't to avoid your page from reloading when form is submitted

I suggest you use this flow

1 -> `data-callback='onSubmit'` attribute is no longer need

2 -> remove function `onSubmit` and replace it with event listener

this code will listen if your form register is being submitted

```
  $(document)
    .off('submit', '.register')
    .on('submit', '.register', function(e) {
        /** Do what you want when submitting the form **/
        var siteurl= 'http://localhost/test/';
        var formdata = $('.register').serialize();
        $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: siteurl+"app/ajax/test.php",
                data: formdata
            })
            .done(function( msg ) {
                alert(msg);

            });

        /** prevent form from submitting to your form action page **/
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

3 -> also `document.getElementById("register").submit();` remove this since your form is already been submitting

`e.preventDefault();` what this line do is it will prevent form from submitting to your form action page

Comment: thanks a lot, but when i remove onSubmit, and replace it event listener as you said, the form is entirely not working..

Comment: let's continue here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143820/javascript-return-false-is-not-working

Comment: iam very new at stackoverflow so i dont have permission to use chat room

Comment: @mkrts also can you screen shot your form

Comment: @mkrts I see that's why it's not working it should `$(document).on('submit'` not `$('.VerenRegister').on('submit'` you didn't totally follow my code

Comment: ok, i changed but same resault. this is not simple ajax form as i said google invisible reCAPTCHA